# Convert SQL query to Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a sql query:

```
select `id` from `users` 
where (
        select count(*) 
        from `user_event` as `uev` 
        where `uev`.`leader_id` = `users`.`id`
      ) > 1
```

How can I convert it to Eloquent Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have set up the relationship you can use the `has()` method for that:

```
$users = User::select('id')->has('events', '>', 1)->get();
```

If you want an array of users ids (since you're only selecting the id) you can also use `lists()`:

```
$ids = User::has('events', '>', 1)->lists('id');
```

---

Since you asked, this would be an alternative method (not tested though)

```
User::where(DB::raw('1'), '<', function($q){
    $q->from('user_event')
      ->where('user_event.leader_id', 'users.id');
})->get();
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much !!!. Assuming I don't use `has`. Do you have any other ways?

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe with some raw queries, but that's not really Eloquent anymore ;) I see no reason why not to use `has` if you're using Eloquent anyways..

Comment: I am studying Query Builder and Eloquent so can you give me the raw query to do it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I got a error: `QLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: Hmm. Okay, then it probably doesn't work that way... If you figure something out feel free to suggest an edit